# Test application for muliple open connections?

Tags: android, web-services, sockets, android-networking

I don't know how to put this but here goes. My application has creating connections with the server. How can I test the application to check whether connections are getting closed and resources are released or not.

Comment: try fetching some data from server ...response will tell u that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$ adb shell netstat | grep ESTABLISHED
```

or something similar to monitor the connections.

If you are interested in a specific server you can do

```
$ adb shell netstat | grep <SERVER_IP> | grep ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You have to install some `grep` (I guess from cygwin) if using Windoze